# Installing rJava on SLES 12

Tags: r, suse, rjava

I am attempting to install rJava on Suse SLES 12. I have installed JDK 7 (7u51), fixed my `JAVA_HOME`, run `sudo R CMD javareconf` and installed the package suggested here: [rJava won't install on openSUSE 13.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667909/rjava-wont-install-on-opensuse-13-2).

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -o libjri.so Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared -L/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.all:38: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmptpO8Z9/R.INSTALL7e795f7a8704/rJava/jri/src'
Makefile.all:21: recipe for target 'src/JRI.jar' failed
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmptpO8Z9/R.INSTALL7e795f7a8704/rJava/jri'
Makevars:14: recipe for target 'jri' failed
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/opt/node_apps/acas-2016-02-03-13-07-09/r_libs/rJava’
```

I have attempted to update `zypper install libpcre1` and `zypper install liblzma5`, but updating them did not change the error message.

I know that on Ubuntu there is a `liblzma-dev` that could help (https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/8), but I can't find a similar package for Suse.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: You're missing the libraries it lists - check your system to find if you have them at all and where (`libpcre.so`, `liblzma.so` and `libz.so`). It's possible that you have them with some suffix which prevents linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the following RPM packages

- xz-devel
- pcre-devel
- pcre-devel-static
- zlib-devel

and try again. I'm not quite sure right now, but if that didn't help, please make sure that these packages are installed aswell:

- xz
- libpcre1
- liblzma5